# ASP.NET: Bold parts of text using HtmlGenericControl

Tags: asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I am a complete ASP.NET newbie, so this will probably be simple.

I have a label which text is set dynamically in the code behind using the following pseudo code

```
label.Text = string.Format(SOME-DYNAMIC-MESSAGE(ID,1), name, day);
```

The SOME-DYNAMIC-MESSAGE has a form of, where {0} and {1} refers to variables name and day.

```
Hello {0}, today is {1}.
```

I need to make those **variables bold**. I am trying to wrap them in span, so I can access them from CSS using this code

```
HtmlGenericControl bold = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    bold.InnerText = name;
    bold.Attributes.Add("class", "bold");

label.Text = string.Format(SOME-DYNAMIC-MESSAGE(ID,1), bold, day);
```

but it doesn't work, no extra wrapper added. It even stopped to show me the the content of the variable.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: label.Text = string.Format(SOME-DYNAMIC-MESSAGE(ID,1), "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">" + bold + "</span>", "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">" + day + "</span>");

Comment: I'll paste it as answer then :)

Comment: My solution will make ALL tokens within your format string BOLD by wrapping each of them in a span and then applying a style to that span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
label.Text = string.Format(SOME-DYNAMIC-MESSAGE(ID,1), "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">" + bold + "</span>", "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">" + day + "</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick sample app (Console app) to demonstrate an approach.  I think you are trying to format the input string for `String.Format` and make the `font-weight` of the token (`{0}`, `{1}`, etc...) **bold**.

use this `Func<string,string>` to format the input string.  then add the following CSS to your html page:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = @"Hello {0}, today is {1}.";

        Func<string, string> SomeDynamicMessage = s => {
            var val = s;
            val = val.Replace("{", "<span class='bold-token'>{");
            val = val.Replace("}", "}</span>");
            return val;
        };

        Console.WriteLine(SomeDynamicMessage(input));

        // output: Hello <span class='bold-token'>{0}</span>, today is <span class='bold-token'>{1}</span>.
        var final = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Css snippet:

```
.bold-token { font-weight: bold; }
```

Final output:

```
Hello <span class='bold-token'>{0}</span>, today is <span class='bold-token'>{1}</span>
```

**EDIT -- MORE INFO**

Here is how you should use it:

```
var input = @"Hello {0}, today is {1}.";
label.Text = string.Format(SomeDynamicMessage(input), "test", "Thursday");
```

and the output would be:

```
Hello <span class='bold-token'>test</span>, today is <span class='bold-token'>Thursday</span>
```

Comment: this wont work if input was var input = string.Format("Hello {0}, today is {1}.", "test", "thursday"); as result would already be "Hello test, today is thursday" and curly brackets would be replaced.